# C/C++ default value/value assigned to variable is never used

Tags: c++, c, initialization, default, misra

I like to always initialse local variables, e.g

```
int32_t result = 0;
```

I thought this is good programming style because "result" can never become uninitialised, independent of whether following if-constructs set it or not.

But now I am trying out a static code checker tool (C_STAT for IAR embedded workbench) and this complains that in the function below, MISRA-C++ rule 2008-01-06 ("shall not contain instances of non-volatile variables being given values that are never subsequently used") and MISRA C:2012 rule 2.2c ("no dead code") and CWE 563 ("unused variable") are violated.

```
// gets signal1 - signal2 (checks range of value)
int16_t getSignalDifferenceFromFloat(float signal1, int16_t signal2)
{
    int32_t result = 0; // <-- this assignment makes the violation 
                        // ... but I feel better with it

    if (signal1 > 65535.0)
    {
        // because result cannot be smaller than the max value of TSignal
        result = 32767;
    }
    else if (signal1 < -65535.0)  // <-- here an else  was missing
    {
        // because result cannot be larger than the min value of TSignal
        result = -32768;
    }
    else
    {
        result = (int32_t)signal1 - (int32_t)signal2;

        if (result < -32768)
        {
            result = -32768;
        }
        else if (result > 32767)
        {
            result = 32767;
        }
    }

    return (int16_t) result;
}
```

original Question: What do you think about it?

New Questions:

1. Are there good coding standards which require always immediate initialisation of declared local variables?
2. Is the code checker too pedantic (some compilers do not complain at this place but would complain it the variable would be completely stay unused)? I make it for years but I cannot remember where I had seen it.

Update: In the meantime (Sept 2021) I use pclint with default settings. It also checks misra C++ rule 0-1-6 (variable not subsequently used) and others, but does not complain with this example. If I change the code and do not return this variable, the warning comes as expected. I think it is correct that pclint does not give a warning here.

Comment: Are you sure? Your first if is pointless... the second if/else will always change the value of result.

Comment: That first analyse don't seem very relevant. Even the most basic optimizing compiler can remove an unnecessary initialization.

Comment: First of all, please note that C and C++ are two *very* different languages, and while parts might seem similar there might be minute details that makes a big difference in behavior and semantics. Second of all, what's the use of using `int32_t` for a variable that you're going to cast to `int16_t` anyway? Lastly, are you sure about your `if` followed by `if ... else`? Should you not have `if ... else if ... else`?

Comment: are those the only static analysis issues you get?  What about the unnecessary comparison of an integer with a double or the magic numbers?

Comment: You need to ask a different question than _"What do you think about it?"_, such as _"How can I write the code so that it conforms with both local and MISRA standards?"_.  Canvassing opinion is OT on SO.

Comment: @Wiliam_Wilson: You are right, there was an else lost. But with this the situation remains the same.

Comment: @Some programmer dude: I was using int32_t in order to avoid that the difference of the float value (e.g. 100000) and the int16_t (e.g. -30000) gives a value which is out of range of int16_t. In this case however it was garenteed that the values are not out of range of int32_t.

Comment: Since you must still *clamp* the result, why not use an existing function for that, like [`std::clamp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp)? As in `return static_cast<int16_t>(std::clamp(signal1 - signal2, -32768, 32767));`

Comment: Clamp is a good idea - I did not know this function which seems to be new in C++17. My code was originally programmed some years ago for a smaller microcontroller and is integrated in the other code which is C++ by the use of extern "C". Therefore no static_cast and not std::clamp can be used. I am already thinking if it is worth to switch to C++ completely.

Comment: MISRA-C:2012 is not applicable to C++ so you should remove that tag. Using C++ is a MISRA-C violation in itself, you'd need to use MISRA-C++ instead.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with MISRA.

The unnecessary initialisation of a variable can allow for sloppy code as it defeats tools that check for uninitialised variables.

In your particular case you could localise `result` to the final `else` case and return prematurely in the other cases. But that's not to everyone's taste either.

Comment: The question kind of invites opinion; but that is no reason to give one - opinion is OT on SO.

Comment: @Clifford: I take this as "polite opinion", i.e. this style must be insisted upon.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Our internal coding style forbids to return prematurely. This is also true for Misra C++ (2008-6-6-5).

Comment: @Bathsheba: And that's why it's just your _opinion_: I would (almost) insist on the opposite opinion. Now do you see why we don't answer subjective questions on SO? You are putting something forth as fact that is, in fact, not fact.

Comment: It is no longer an opinion if you have enough authoritative sources to back it up. MISRA-C forbids _dead code_, which is defined as code that can be removed without affecting the outcome of the program, with the exception of expression that are explicitly cast to `(void)` by the programmer. Dead code is regarded as a safety hazard. Authoritative sources: MISRA-C:2012, IEC61507, ISO26262, DO-178C.

Answer (score 1):

Static analysers apply the rules you define - some of these rules will conflict because you are expected to set them to match your local coding standard.  I imagine there is also a rule that may or may not be enabled that *requires* initialisation of all variables; and you cannot do both.

Pick a non-conflicting rule set that matches your preferred standard. Which you choose is a matter of opinion so not really a valid SO question.

Answer (score 1):

Most good static analysers will provide you with data flow analysis - which warn you of possible paths leaving uninitialised variables.

Taking your example, say you (accidentally) missed one of the later assignments, this would not be detected by SA:

```
/// gets signal1 - signal2 (checks range of value)
int16_t getSignalDifferenceFromFloat(float signal1, int16_t signal2)
{
    int32_t result = 0; // <-- this assignment makes the violation 
        // ... but I feel better with it

    if (signal1 > 65535.0)
    {
        // commented out this line
        // No data-flow anomoly detected
        // result = 32767;
    }

    // Snip rest of code

    return (int16_t) result;
}
```

The MISRA Guidelines are not perfect, by any stretch, but we try and prevent the obvious... and uninitialised variables are quite easy to detect - as long as you don't try and fudge the issue.

It's a bit like sticking a cast in, just to shut up the Static Analysis tool......

[See profile for disclaimers]